# vba Loop thru rows in range return column value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, row

At wits end here.  Just trying to return the value of specific column(4) while looping thru rows in range.  Here's what I have so far.

```
 With sht
       'Iterate over rows in used range        
        For Each loopRow In workRange.Rows:            
           myVariable = .Cells(loopRow, 4).Value                
           MsgBox myVariable

        Next loopRow

End With
```

Comment: `myVariable = loopRow.Cells(4).Value`

Comment: that's it.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but here's how I normally prefer to traverse rows and columns in Excel with VBA, with row and column offset counter variables.  This sample will print the cells in column D to the immediate window.

Given this:

[image]

This code identifies the values of interest:

```
Public Sub GetCol4()
Dim Rng As Excel.Range, rowOffset As Long
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Do Until IsEmpty(Rng.Offset(rowOffset, 0).Value)
        Debug.Print Rng.Offset(rowOffset, 3).Value
        rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

...and results in this being left in the Immediate Window:

[image]